# Promise for getting the title of a web page never resolves with Protractor and Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

The following protractor/jasmine test code only prints out 1 and 2, and then hangs and times out.

It appears to be an issue with either the click() action on the button element, or the promise on the getTitle method on the browser object, or both.

Does anyone have a solution to this, or a better way of doing what I'm doing?

**Code:**

```
it('should allow successful login', function() {   
    browser.get('http://192.168.0.100/src/');
    browser.waitForAngular();

    var titlePromise = browser.getTitle();
    titlePromise.then(function(text){
      console.log("1**************", text);
    });

    var titlePromise = browser.getTitle();
    titlePromise.then(function(text){
      console.log("2**************", text);
    });

    element.all(by.model('credentials.username')).first().sendKeys('foo');
    element.all(by.model('credentials.password')).first().sendKeys('bar');
    var loginBtn = element.all(by.cssContainingText('.btn', 'Login')).first();
    loginBtn.click();
    browser.sleep(5000);

    var titlePromise = browser.getTitle();
    titlePromise.then(function(text){
      console.log("3**************", text);
    });    
  });
});
```

**Error:**

> Error: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page
>   after 11 seconds. Please see
>   https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md

Answer (score 4):

I may not have enough information, but here are some things to try:

1. As obvious as this is, have you read through each case that will cause a timeout in the linked doc https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md ? One that has got me before is Protractor will never load if you have $timeout in use in your Angular app.
2. Are you sure you're selecting the loginBtn correctly? You may want to Testing Out Protractor Interactively: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md. From protractor directory /node_modules/protractor:

   $ node ./bin/elementexplorer.js http://192.168.0.100/src/
3. If you're logging in and going to another page, instead of sleeping to wait for the next page to load, wait until it's changed:

   `browser.driver.wait(function() {
     return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
       return /logged-in-url/.test(url);
     });
   });`

Comment: It smells like problem #1 that you mentioned, because I do use $timeout, polling, and $interval in my app. However, none are in use in the process of  running this test, so that confuses me.

The loginBtn is being selected correctly. I watch it work the instance of chrome protractor starts up.

Tried number three with no change in results. This is starting to annoy me. 5 days of experimenting with selenium and I haven't found any good ways to test my app.

Comment: element is the Protractor specific object. The first 2 tests work because they are selenium, not Protractor. My guess is Protractor isn't able to load. I'd strongly recommend reading through that doc.

Comment: I gave up on that, and have decided to go with selenium-webdriver by itself. I finally got it to work and not skip anything or hang anywhere. I'll be honest, a lot of this selenium stuff seems super wild-west like, and its disappointing, as well as discouraging. How can angular back a testing framework that doesn't work for all angular apps!?

Comment: A lot of people say use selenium for your login page, and then use protractor specific once logged in. Yes it's the wild west. It's not so bad when you're experimenting on company time ;).

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten that all interaction with the document is done through [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Your code ought to look something like the untested block below.

Note also that `browser.waitForAngular` is [not needed](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.waitForAngular), "Protractor automatically applies this command before every WebDriver action."

Not sure why you call `getTitle` so often, but I left it in, in case it makes the refactor more clear.

```
it('should allow successful login', function() {   
    browser.get('http://192.168.0.100/src/')
    .then(function(){
        return browser.getTitle()
    })
    .then(function(text){
        console.log("1**************", text);
        return browser.getTitle();
    })
    .then(function(text) {
        console.log("2**************", text);
        return browser.getTitle()
    })
    .then(function (text) {
        console.log("3**************", text);
        element.all(by.model('credentials.username')).first().sendKeys('foo');
    })
    .then(function () {
        element.all(by.model('credentials.password')).first().sendKeys('bar');
    })
    .then(function () {
        element.all(by.cssContainingText('.btn', 'Login')).first().click();
    })
    .then(function () {
        browser.sleep(5000); // Better to use ExpectedConditions to wait something
    })
    .then(function () {
        var titlePromise = browser.getTitle();
        return browser.getTitle()
    })
    .then(function (text) {
        console.log("3**************", text);
    });
});
```